# How to know which file a specific function is in with gdb?

Tags: gdb

Anyone knows how to know which file a specific function is in with gdb?

Answer (score 2):

there is also info func which accepts a regular expression.

```
(gdb) info func ^bp1$
All functions matching regular expression "^bp1$":

File test.c:
void bp1();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the function name is `someFunc`, first find the address of the function:

```
info address someFunc
```

And assuming you got the adress `someAddress`, use `list` with that address:

```
list *someAddress
```

Example from a gdb session:

```
(gdb) info address main
Symbol "main" is a function at address 0x406159.
(gdb) list *0x406159
0x406159 is in main (../src/staapp-test.cpp:221).
```